# Center UIView with flexible Height and Width in UIView both horizontally and vertically

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, autolayout, interface-builder

I want to center an `UIView` containing a `UIImageView` in an other `UIView` both horizontally and vertically.

So i placed all Items in Interface Builder and set Constraints for center vertically and horizontally. Then i added max height and width to avoid the inner `UIView` excessing the outer `UIView`.
But still Interface Builder tells me I need to specify X and Y Constraint for the inner `UIView`.

What did i do wrong?

Reason i'm needing this is, i need a `UIImage` which can be landscape or portrait format displayed centered in the `UIView`. Also there should be an Icon overlaying the `UIImage` in the lower right corner. So i thought best solution would be to make a `UIView` containing both images and place it centered in the main uiview. But it seems autolayout won't let me do this.

Can somebody hint me in the right direction please?

**EDIT**

For more Clarification on what i want.

I need a UIView having its Center Point fixed at exaclty one point in its superview.
How can i do this with maintaining flexible height and width and using autolayout?

Comment: did you set autolayout for both imageview & inner uiview

Comment: I set autolayout constraints for all uiimageviews and uiviews. they are all correct and accepted by interfacebuilder. Only thing it complains about is not having a X and Y constraint for the uiview with the flexible height and width.

Comment: What is going on is , You have Constraints for center vertically and horizontally. But it is not satisfying height . & Width Constraints  ,means your view knows from where it should be centre but it has no fixed height and width to satisfy autolayout engine

Comment: **i need a UIImage which can be landscape or portrait format displayed** it is not been possible to set  Uiview as per image content mode (i.e if image is aspect fit ) in case of image your image has some space from left and right part and same with portrait

Comment: flexible height and width of what ?, subview should resize ? , yes then according to what ?

Comment: Why don't you set leading , trailing , top , bottom of your subview according to your superview ? Because subview never get out of superview if i am correct then

Answer (score -4):

Use horizontal,vertical and Leading [image]

Comment: This is not answer of this question , Please add it as comment as you have enough reputation to do so

Comment: This is very wrong auto layout , You have top constraint as well as you have centre   horizontal constraint too.  and same for leading

Comment: since i need the center of the uiview fixed in one place and not the origin, your answer is not correct.